# React Swipper when press tab key doesn't advance to the next slide

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, swiper.js

My React Swiper works as expected with the mouse clicks, but for accesibility, some slides has a button. So, when I press the tab key, it show the button, but the slides are cut like the image shows and the navigation buttons disappear, I need that everything continuos showing and when a slide has the button focused, the div (slide) parent to be completed showed too. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: You should choose an accessible slider library, this one is no good. Their Top Notch features don’t list accessibility. Fixing that in 3rd-party components via their API almost never works. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75178087/how-do-i-add-screen-reader-functionality-to-select-2-combo-box-and-bootstraps-d/75181949#75181949

Comment: thanks, but I have an example with non-react and works properly when tab, I doesn't truncate the images.

Comment: I don't see how that is relevant. If the react implementation is faulty,